# JQuery datatable - suppress display of row count

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a html table that I have used the JQuery datatable plugin as follows:

```
(#client-table).dataTable()
```

This displays "Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries" below. Is there a way to hide this text or not show it at all.

Comment: How about simple using CSS : display:none ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -

```
$('#client-table').dataTable('bInfo': false);
```

https://www.datatables.net/usage/features#binfo